# Why request.GET.get('tag', '') returns C rather than C++ in django GET request?

Tags: python, django

This is my code in django template:

```
{% for tag in tags %}
          <a href="{% url 'tag_find' %}?tag={{ tag }}" > {{ tag }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

in view.py:

```
def tag_find(request):
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    tag = request.GET.get('tag', '')
    print('show_tag:', tag)
    ........
```

Some example are not working perfectly, like:

When tag is `C++` then `request.GET.get()` shows `C`, when returning tag from template is `Portraits&Caricatures` then `request.GET.get()` shows `Portraits`. I have no idea why `request.GET()` cuts some part of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [**`|urlencode`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-urlencode) the value for the tag, the `+` character is used for spaces:

```
{% for tag in tags %}
    <a href="{% url 'tag_find' %}?tag={{ tag|urlencode }}" > {{ tag }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```